AWS application load balancer and socket.io not working as intended
So I have an application load balancer which routes requests to my application ECS tasks. Basically the load balancer listens on port 80 and 443 and route the requests to my application port (5050). When I configured the target group for those listeners (80 and 443), I selected IP type in the target group configuration but didn’t register any target (IP). So what happens now is, if any request comes in from 80 or 443, it just automatically register 2 IP addresses (Bcus I am running two task on ECS) in my application target group registered targets.
I have a requirement now to integrate socket.io and it’s on port 4454. When I try to edit the listener rule for 80 and 443 to add socket target group so it also routes traffic to my socket port (4454), it doesn’t work. This only work if I create a new listener on a different protocol (8443 or 8080) but it doesn’t register IPs automatically in the registered target in socket target group. I manually have to copy the registered IPs that are automatically populated in the application target group and paste it in the socket target group registered targets for it to work. This would have been fine if my application end state doesn’t require auto scaling. For future state, So when I deploy those ECS tasks in production environment, I’ll be configuring auto scaling so more tasks are spinned up when traffic is high. But this creates a problem for me as I can’t be manually copying the IPs from the application targets group to socket target group just in case those tasks grow exponentially when traffic is high. I would want this process to be automatic but unfortunately my socket target group doesn’t register IPs automatically as my application target group does. I would be really grateful if someone can help out or point out what I’m doing wrong
I have tried adding the socket target group to the listeners on 80 and 443 but it still doesn’t work. I have also tried creating a new listener for the socket target group but still IPs are not automatically registering in the target group
